# Какой максимальный объем информаций, который можно прочитать с помощью read в си?

Tags: linux, c

Какой максимальный объем информаций, который можно прочитать с помощью read в си?

Comment: Весь винчестер, если хотите.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Думаю вопрос заключается в том, сколько можно прочитать за один вызов read. А тут не все так однозначно, зависит от ограничений ядра. Подозреваю, что например при выполнении read из сетевого сокета нельзя за раз прочитать больше, чем буфер сокета со стороны ядра, а это десятки килобайт. С диском думаю то же могут быть похожие ограничения, но конечно гораздо большего размера

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html : On Linux, read() (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
       0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
       actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
       systems.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(2,147,479,552) bytes согласно документации http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html